# Why doesn't Python always require spaces around keywords?

Tags: python, pypy, cpython

Why can spaces sometimes be omitted before and after key words? For example, why is the expression `2if-1e1else 1` valid?

Seems to work in both CPython 2.7 and 3.3:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 12 2012, 09:50:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2if-1e1else 1
2

$ python3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Nov 12 2012, 10:01:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2if-1e1else 1
2
```

and even in PyPy:

```
$ pypy
Python 2.7.2 (341e1e3821ff, Jun 07 2012, 15:42:54)
[PyPy 1.9.0 with GCC 4.2.1] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``PyPy 1.6 released!''
>>>> 2if-1e1else 1
2
```

Comment: that's starting to look like perl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Identifiers in python are described as:

```
identifier ::= (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

Hence, `2if` can't be an identifier hence if must be `2`,`if`. Similar logic applies to the rest of the expression.

Basically interpreting `2if-1e1else 1` would go something like this (the full parsing would be quite complicated):

`2if` not valid identifier, `2` matches digit `digit ::= "0"..."9"`,`if` matches keyword.
`-1e1else`, `-1` is the unary negation (`u_expr ::= power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr`)  of **:** ( `1` which matches `intpart` in `exponentfloat ::= (intpart | pointfloat) | exponent`
 , `e1` is exponent `exponent ::= ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digit+`.) You can see expressions of the form `Ne+|-x` yields a float this from:

```
>>> type(2e3)
<type 'float'>
```

then the `else` is seen as the keyword, and `-1` etc..

You can peruse the [**gammar**](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/grammar.txt) to read more about it.

Comment: *"...`-1` matches `intpart`..."* wait, what? Isn't `-` a unary operator?

Comment: So basically, it's like this because preventing it would make the grammar/parser more complicated.

Comment: @asmeurer It's like this, because it *is* the grammar (if that makes sense)

Comment: Well, duh, but I'm pretty sure the grammar didn't write itself. Every aspect of the Python language is there for reason.

Comment: Why prevent it when no sane programmer would write code like that.

Comment: Even stranger because keywords can follow a letter without any space inbetween: `2jif.1jelse.1`

Comment: For extra fun: using `2if` in the expression is accepted, but using `2else` is not; this is probably because the latter is parsed as `2e???` with `???` being a non-number, which is a syntax error.